# CSS style sheet implementation

Tags: html, css

I've downloaded a style sheet that I want to use for a personal HTML webpage of mine. Quick question about implementing said style sheet. A screenshot of the folder is here: 
http://imgur.com/94m11mz

I know to have an external style sheet I need to use the link tag, something akin to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="external_style_sheet.css" type="text/css">
```

My questions are these:

1) Would href= "name of the .css files?" i.e href="default.css"

2) I'm not sure what to do with 2 .css files. Do I link to both of them? Meaning do I have 2 link tags? One going to default.css and one going to fonts.css? Such as:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css" type="text/css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" type="text/css">
```

3) Do I need to include all of the folders/.css files in the same folder as my HTML document? Or can I move that to a different folder if I explicitly type out the location to in href="name of .css file here" thing?

Comment: Yes, yes, and you can move it into a dif folder

Answer (score 0):

You can move them to your own folder, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" type="text/css">
```

And yes you need one link tag per css file you want to include in your html file(s).

Answer (score 0):

You will need two link tags as they are different files, the folder structure depends on how you think it is appropriate.
Generally it is a relative path like '..css/yourstylesheet.css'

Answer (score 0):

href takes the virtual path. thats like say you have css folder in your root directory and the css file present in that then href = "css{your css filename}".

Answer (score 0):

> **Question 1:** Would href= "name of the .css files?" i.e href="default.css"

**Yes you should name css with .css extension**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="external_style_sheet.css" type="text/css">
```

> **Question 2:** I'm not sure what to do with 2 .css files. Do I link to both of
>   them? Meaning do I have 2 link tags? One going to default.css and one
>   going to fonts.css?

**Yes**, you can use two link tags but keep in mind if you have same class or id name in the two stylesheet it will take the style of last stylesheet.

**For eg:**

if you have `<div class="sample"> hi </div>` in your html
and in your **default.css** if you have `.sample{color:red;}` and in your **font.css** you have `.sample{color:blue}` then the text `"hi"` will appear **blue** in color as you have linked **font.css** second.

> **Question 3:** Do I need to include all of the folders/.css files in the same
>   folder as my HTML document? Or can I move that to a different folder
>   if I explicitly type out the location to in href="name of .css file
>   here" thing?

**It is highly recommended to keep all `.css extension` files under a single folder.** so that you can search for the stylesheet easily if you have large sum of files in your site.

And you should link like wise the stylesheet if you have it in a separate folder.

Folder Name: CSS
File Name : Default.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Default.css" type="text/css">
```